# How can you send one email for all thread groups using jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am using smtp sampler in Jmeter to send email. The issue that I am having is: it is sending email for each thread group. If I have number of thread =5, ill be getting 5 emails. How can I send one email with attached report for large number of threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [tearDown thread group](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27717420/2079249), in short it is more like `junit`'s `@AfterClass` method....

> [A special type of ThreadGroup](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) that can be utilized to perform
>   Post-Test Actions. The behavior of these threads is exactly like a
>   normal Thread Group element. The difference is that these type of
>   threads execute after the test has finished executing its regular
>   Thread Groups.

[image]

Comment: Great worked fine. Thanks a lot. Now I can get one email for large amount of thread group (users).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-if-controller-and-get-pie) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function to trigger the request which sends the email only for specific thread.

__threadNum() function basically returns current virtual user number (1 for first, 2 for second, etc.) so if you put the following line into the If Controller's "Condition" area:

```
${__threadNum} == 3
```

The children of the If Controller will be executed only for virtual user number 3.

Demo:

[image: If Controller Demo]